# Select the next div after the current form on click submit button jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the next div with class `comment-replies` after the current form and `prepend` data. There are more divs with the same class on the page and forms.

```
<div class="hide">
                <br>
                <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"],ENT_QUOTES,"utf-8")?>" method="post">


            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control comment" rows="6" name="comment"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-3" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                    <input hidden class="reply-comment-id" value="23">
                    <input class="form-control btn-xs add-reply" type="submit" name="reply" value="REPLY">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
            </div>
<div class="comment-replies">
               <!--replies-->
               <?php $this->get_replies($comment['comment_id']); ?>
            </div>
```

jQuery code for the button.

```
$('.add-reply').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var upId = $('#upload-id').val();
    var usId = $('#user-id').val();
    var cId = $(this).prev('input').val();
    var the_form = $(this).closest("form");
    var textComment = the_form.find('textarea[name="comment"]');
    var com = textComment.val();
    $.post('add_comment.php',{cid:cId,upId:upId,usId:usId,reply:com},function(data){
        the_form.nextUntil('div').prepend(data);
    //$('.comment-replies').prepend(data); this append to every div with the current class.
        the_form.addClass('hide');
    });

});
```

[example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhdk9s28/3/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the code that worked for me.

```
$('.add-reply').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var upId = $('#upload-id').val();
    var usId = $('#user-id').val();
    var cId = $(this).prev('input').val();
    var the_form = $(this).closest(".myDiv");
    var textComment = the_form.find('textarea[name="comment"]');
    var com = textComment.val();
    //$.post('add_comment.php',{cid:cId,upId:upId,usId:usId,reply:com},function(data){
    var data = 'Dummy data';
        the_form.next('.comment-replies').prepend(data);
    //$('.comment-replies').prepend(data); this append to every div with the current class.
      //  the_form.addClass('hide');
    //});

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bhdk9s28/4/

Comment: there are more than one form on the page.

Comment: The reason it didn't work is because your Fiddle code is not the same as the code you posted in the OP. Please edit your post to reflect that. I had to go back and change the fiddle. Now I have it working

Comment: working well, thanks. Also change your answer to reflect the one on jsfiddle because it's the one that worked, not this one.